# Azure MVC Benchmarking Metrics and Performance Expectations

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure

I've been googling for the last hour and haven't found anything substantial. I've inherited an application from a previous development company who was hired on contract. It is an MVC 5 application that is deployed to Azure as a Cloud Service and runs on 10 A4 VM instances. The codebase I've inherited is all kinds of crazy. The entire thing was written synchronously from the database layer all the way through cache access and into the views. I've been trying to convince my employers for a few weeks now that they were essentially ripped off by the contractors who had no idea what they were doing and big rewrites are in order

Thats 10 machines each with 8 cores, 14 GB of RAM and 240GB HDD. We service a pretty substantial amount of traffic. At peak times our site will have around 50-60 thousand active users with about half that many page loads per minute. There are no serious analytics or CPU intensive operations happening in the background, just retrieving data from either the cache or data layer, rendering razor pages and thats it. At this level of traffic the CPU level of our Cloud Service will sometimes hit 80 percent and as the site grows management is talking about just throwing more VMs at the problem.

My question is does that reflect the kind of performance we should be seeing considering how computing power we're consuming? The fact that it takes us 80 cores and 140 GB of RAM to be able to service 30k page views per minute is in my eyes a sign of massive inefficiencies in the code base. The company is "risk adverse" though so tossing around words like "re-write" and "start from scratch" are not always well received.

I'm hoping to find evidence both anecdotally and through benchmarks that might demonstrate a much higher traffic throughput. Even for someone to say "I run a website in Azure that does 10k page views per minute and I can do it with 2 A4s" would help my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting issue you have.

Hopefully these resources can help you out:

http://www.troyhunt.com/2014/09/10-things-i-learned-about-rapidly.html

and

http://www.troyhunt.com/2014/07/scaling-standard-azure-website-to-380k.html

Comment: Thanks good reads, very helpful information.